# AppEngine Bulk upload along with files

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py, google-tasks-api

I need to do bulk upload data from CSV file to Datastore. Although the data in the CSV file is also having a field which should be URL to a file.

Each row(person) is mapped to an associated file. which either i can upload in Google Cloud Storage. Although at runtime how can i upload the file and then get the URL and update the CSV file. Then use the CSV file to do Bulk upload.

Need to have a solution for this.

THanks for Help

Comment: I think you're mistaking stackoverflow for a free coding service. Stackoverflow is here to help you with your solution not to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this

1. Write stuff in your request handler and perform the task, raw data can be uploaded to gae as a  project resources, there are some size limits obviously
2. The better way is to enable remote api , then use remote api python script to batch upload stuff or write some code in python which points to  your remote datasource.